# Find location where smaller array matches larger array the most

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.4

I need to find where a smaller 2d array, array1 matches the closest inside another 2d array, array2.

- array1 with have the size of grid_size 46x46 to 96x96.
- array2 will be larger (184x184).

I only have access to numpy.

I am currently trying to use the [Tversky formula](https://docs.eyesopen.com/toolkits/python/graphsimtk/measure.html#tversky) but am not tied to it.

Efficiency is the most important part as this will run many times. My current solution shown below is very slow.

```
for i in range(array2.shape[0] - grid_size):
    for j in range(array2.shape[1] - grid_size):
        r[i, j] = np.sum(array2[i:i+grid_size, j:j+grid_size] == array1 ) / (np.sum(array2[i:i+grid_size, j:j+grid_size] != array1 ) + np.sum(Si[i:i+grid_size, j:j+grid_size] == array1 ))
```

Edit:
The goal is to find the location where a smaller image matches another image.

Comment: Look into normalized cross-correlation, and convolution

Comment: What do you mean by "closest"? What is the intended purpose of finding this matching portion. What is in the arrays? ints, float? spare or dense? are the values bound to a range?

Comment: Im looking for an element by comparison. The array is integers coming from an image

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have been trying that. A problem Im having is that if the smaller array is all 0s, convolution returns nothing

Comment: Isn't this substantially image registration (using only translation)?

Comment: @norok2 It does look like that would solve the problem. I could find a way to do it in just numpy, do have an example?

Comment: A crude and slow way would be using two nested loops as you are doing. You just need to polish it a bit (e.g. making sure that you compute the distance between `array1` and the `(i,j)`-based view of `array2` with matching size, storing/updating the minimum every time a new one is found. I do not have already written code for this. Note that if your distance involves element-wise multiplication and one of your inputs is all `0`s, your distance may be `0` independently of the position, i.e. every location is the *best* (equally worse?) location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an FFT/convolution based approach that minimizes Euclidean distance:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import fft

N = 184
n = 46
pad = 192

def best_offs(A,a):
    A,a = A.astype(float),a.astype(float)
    Ap,ap = (np.zeros((pad,pad)) for _ in "Aa")
    Ap[:N,:N] = A
    ap[:n,:n] = a
    sim = fft.irfft2(fft.rfft2(ap).conj()*fft.rfft2(Ap))[:N-n+1,:N-n+1]
    Ap[:N,:N] = A*A
    ap[:n,:n] = 1
    ref = fft.irfft2(fft.rfft2(ap).conj()*fft.rfft2(Ap))[:N-n+1,:N-n+1]
    return np.unravel_index((ref-2*sim).argmin(),sim.shape)

# example
# random picture
A = np.random.randint(0,256,(N,N),dtype=np.uint8)
# random offset
offy,offx = np.random.randint(0,N-n+1,2)
# sub pic at random offset
# randomly flip half of the least significant 75% of all bits
a = A[offy:offy+n,offx:offx+n] ^ np.random.randint(0,64,(n,n))

# reconstruct offset
oyrec,oxrec = best_offs(A,a)
assert offy==oyrec and offx==oxrec

# speed?
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit(lambda:best_offs(A,a),number=100)*10,"ms")

# example with zero a
a[...] = 0
# make A smaller in a matching subsquare
A[offy:offy+n,offx:offx+n]>>=1

# reconstruct offset
oyrec,oxrec = best_offs(A,a)
assert offy==oyrec and offx==oxrec
```

Sample run:

```
3.458537160186097 ms
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution precisely what I was looking for. From my quick tests, it's about 150% faster than my solution. I thought fft could work, but I couldn't put all the pieces together. I will study this code for the future.